# Hybris 18.11 conflict with GSON and Stripe

Tags: java, json, gson, stripe-payments, sap-commerce-cloud

For my project I am using hybris v18.11, and using Stripe payment gateway, I need to fetch the rawJsonObject using Stripe's Charge object which is provided via gson library. Below is the code in StripeObject which provides rawJsonObject

```
this.rawJsonObject = ApiResource.GSON.fromJson(this.getLastResponse().body(), JsonObject.class);
```

I fetched `this.getLastResponse().body()` populated String value in hybris project and tried to convert that manually using gson and it was a success.
I am able to fetch rawJsonObject in non-hybris project(normal maven/gradle project) while fetching the same via a hybris project the rawJsonObject returned is empty {}.
I tried with gson v2.8.2 V2.8.6, v2.5 in both hybris and non-hybris project, every time I receive a proper response in the non-hybris project while empty JSON object in hybris project.
I tried with Stripe-java-20.47.0.jar and Stripe-java-20.36.0.jar in the hybris project got the same result empty rawJsonObject.
Any leads will be helpful, also if I missed anything or if I need to test anything else please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening 100% of the time or intermittently? I'm wondering if the response body is perhaps being mutated and made unavailable for some reason.

Have you tried using the built-in `getRawJsonObject()` ([source](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/StripeObject.java#L55))? It looks to record this the first time the response is accessed, so if a stream is consumed perhaps it is preserved here for you.

Comment: It's happening all the time, I have put debug point for built-in getRawJsonObject() and was able to access the response body, it's fine valid Json String. As per the current analysis looks like there is a mismatch for gson version, request to fetch JSON object via GSON.fromJson doesn't go to the intended jar. Working on it will update the thread once I get any solution.